# Converting date and time text to date and time format in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any way to format the following text to date and time format in Excel?  Nothing I try works.

```
Fri, November 16 2018 8:00 PM
```

I have tried doing the following, with no luck.

```
=TEXT("Fri, November 16 2018 8:00 PM","ddd, mmm d yyyy h:mm AM/PM")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid VBA, then you need to use the `DATEVALUE` and `TIMEVALUE` functions. Unfortunately these functions aren't smart enough to convert the text you describe, but you can still split up the text with cell formula prior to inputting into these functions.
The following formula will convert the text `Fri, November 16 2018 8:00 PM` to a date/time value (assuming text is in cell A1).

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1, FIND(" ",A1)+1, FIND("|", SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|",4))-FIND(" ",A1)), " ", ", ", 2)) + TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-FIND("|", SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|",4))))
```

Comment: This answer is the one I used because it sorts.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom UDF and use it like a worksheet function:

```vb
Public Function myDateToDate(inputRng As Range) As Date

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "\w{3},\s(\w+\s\d+\s\d+)\s(\d+:\d+\s\w+)"
        If .test(inputRng.Value) Then
            With .Execute(inputRng.Value)(0).SubMatches
                myDateToDate = CDate(.Item(0)) + CDate(.Item(1))
            End With
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

This will use [**Reg**ular **Ex**pressions (RegEx)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to grab the values in your string, and capture both the date and the time. Since within Excel all a date is is a number, you can add the first capturing group `(\w+\s\d+\s\d+)` (which represents the date) with the second capturing group `(\d+:\d+\s\w+)` (which represents the time) together. *(See how the regex pattern works [here](https://regex101.com/r/PKdyyu/1))*.

After you have done this, you can now use your newly-created UDF by using the worksheet formula `=myDateToDate(A1)` - where `A1` would be replaced with the cell/string that contains your date.

> [image]

---

### If you are unfamiliar with VBA, read on:

> ***How do I access the VBE?***
> You can gain access to VBE by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> while you are inside your workbook.
>
> ***Okay, So I have the VBE open. Now how do I apply this Sub/UDF?***
> In the left pane you will see your workbook object modules. This is called the **Project Explorer**. You will need to create a new module, which you can do by `right-clicking inside the Project Explorer > Insert > Module`:
>
> [image]
>
> Now you can paste the Sub/UDF to this new module and you are all set!

Comment: Thank you, but this solution doesn't sort.

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't sort? There was no mention of sorting anything in your question.

Answer (score 1):

A monstrosity but should be locale independent (either US or UK):

```
=DATE(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,13),5),MONTH(DATEVALUE(LEFT(MID(A1,6,9),FIND(" ",MID(A1,6,10)))&"1")),MID(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,99),FIND(" ",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,99))+1,2))+LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(A1,8)),7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice regex solution above, you can also do it in a different way:

```
Function ConvertToDate(str As String) As Date

    Dim arr() As String

    arr = Split(str, " ")

    ConvertToDate = CDate(arr(3) & "/" & Month("01/" & arr(1) & "/2018") & "/" & arr(2) & " " & arr(4))

End Function
```